# Using conditions for where clause in postgresql select query postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, where-clause, conditional-statements

**Query**

`select * from notice join noticeconcerned using(notice_id) where (nconcerned_section = 'IT' and nconcerned_batch = 2010) or (nconcerned_batch = 2010)  order by n_removeby`

**Result**

[a http://www.4shared.com/download/sgAkE2pKce/notice1.png?lgfp=3000](http://www.4shared.com/download/sgAkE2pKce/notice1.png?lgfp=3000)

I want to display records of students of **either (2010 batch and CS section) or (2010 batch but no section i.e null section)** So in this case only one row should be displayed.

**What i have tried**

`select * from notice join noticeconcerned using(notice_id) where case when (nconcerned_section = 'CS' and nconcerned_batch = 2010) then(____What to use here?) END  or case when (nconcerned_batch = 2010 and nconcerned_section=null) then(___what to use here?) END order by n_removeby`

It would be much helpful if you can explain how to use `case statement` for `where clause`.I found some posts about it but it's confusing for me.

Comment: Please put some data sample(notice and noticeconcerned ), and what you expect as a result!

Comment: My mistake was when i inserted data into the table i didn't insert a `null` but a `' '` i.e a `space`.So `is null` was not working for me.I updated the table and used the query.It worked fine as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your original query, change IT to CS, add and nconcerned_section is null in the second condiiton, and it should return only one result:

```
select * from notice join noticeconcerned using(notice_id) where (nconcerned_section = 'CS' and nconcerned_batch = 2010) or (nconcerned_batch = 2010 and nconcerned_section is null)  order by n_removeby
```

Comment: My mistake was when i inserted data into the table i didn't insert a `null` but a `' '` i.e a `space`.So `is null` was not working for me.I updated the table and used your query.It worked fine as expected.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was when i inserted data into the table i didn't insert a `null` but a `' '` i.e a `space`.So `is null` was not working for me.I updated the table and used the query

`select * from notice join noticeconcerned using(notice_id) where (nconcerned_section = 'CS' and nconcerned_batch = 2010)  or (nconcerned_batch = 2010 and nconcerned_section is null) order by n_removeby`

Now it works.